# saveXML doesn't work, ask for development environment

Tags: php, libxml2, xmldom

I have a test PHP code in DOM XML object like this:

```
<?php

$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0');
// we want a nice output
$doc->formatOutput = true;

$root = $doc->createElement('book');
$root = $doc->appendChild($root);

$title = $doc->createElement('title');
$title->setAttribute('BookName','Bible');
$title->setAttribute('Chapter','1');
$title = $root->appendChild($title);
$title->setAttribute('Verse','2');
$title->setAttribute('EditionName','NIV');

$text = $doc->createTextNode('This is the title');

$text = $title->appendChild($text);


echo "Saving all the document:\n";
echo $doc->saveXML() . "\n";

echo "Saving only the title part:\n";
echo $doc->saveXML($title);

?>
```

From an online PHP code test site(http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/), it does run correctly. I got the following:

---

```
Saving all the document:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<book>
  <title BookName="Bible" Chapter="1" Verse="2" EditionName="NIV">This is the title</title>
</book>

Saving only the title part:
<title BookName="Bible" Chapter="1" Verse="2" EditionName="NIV">This is the title</title>
```

but, when I run the same simple code in my servers, WAMP3.0 in windows, or lamp in Centos6.7, it just got the following:

---

Saving all the document: Saving only the title part:

---

Because I'm debugging another XML DOM object I hope to get an XML object output as a RESP, but my web server all got this that is out of my idea.

development environment:
windows2008r2/wamp3.0/apache2.4.17/php7.0.0/mysql 5.7.9
libxml default enable in version 2.9.2

centos6.7/php 5.6.26/apache 2.0/mysql 5.5.53 /libxml version 2.7.6 enabled dom/xml

Comment: I got the answer from here: 
http://board.phpbuilder.com/showthread.php?10319588-PHP-DOM-saveXML()-prblm-!!

it because browser doesn't show the xml source for some reason

Comment: and remove any space before the tag <?php